# Function return type mismatch between header and corresponding source file in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return-type

I am currently very new to programming, and I am trying to figure out how header files work in C++.

I am trying to create a program that takes two numbers from the user, multiplies them together, and prints them out. However, when I am trying to learn how to include header files to the project, there is something odd that I noticed when I was messing with it. Here are the source files:

main.cpp

```
#include "computeValue.h"
#include <iostream>

float getUserValue()
{
    float userValue{};

    std::cout << "Enter a number.";
    std::cin >> userValue;

    return userValue;
}

int main()
{
    float userValue1{ getUserValue() };
    float userValue2{ getUserValue() };

    std::cout << computeValue( userValue1, userValue2 );
    return 0;
}
```

computeValue.cpp

```
int computeValue( float userValue1, float userValue2 )
{
    return userValue1*userValue2;
}
```

computeValue.h

```
float computeValue( float userValue1, float userValue2 );
```

As you can see, the return type in `computeValue.cpp` and `computeValue.h` for the function `computeValue()` is different. However, to my surprise, this compiles and works perfectly fine! No warnings or errors whatsoever.

I do note that if I switch the return type (making the return type `float` in `computeValue.cpp` and `int` in `computeValue.h`), it seems to break the program and it instead prints out random-looking long numbers instead, but again, no errors or warnings whatsoever.

Can someone give an explanation as to why this happens? Shouldn't this be a redefinition of the function and the compiler should spit out an error? If this is an expected behavior, then what return type will the function `computeValue()` have?

Comment: This should compile but fail to link. If you add `#include "computevalue.h"` to compute.cpp you should get a compiler error.

Comment: The return type is likely not part of the function's decorated/mangled name, so it *may* link, but it certainly won't have the correct behavior at runtime. Either way, this is undefined behavior, if the compile succeeds at all.

Comment: No, fail to link will not produce a program at all. You might have another build that is still there.

Comment: One of the most fun parts of C++ is the bits of the Standard that basically say, "Don't ever do this because the program will be invalid. No diagnostic required."

Comment: Ah I see now, forgive my shallow knowledge about programming! Anyways now I understand that even if it builds and runs it is undefined behavior, not some sort of weird magic of C++ that I do not understand. Thank you for the comments! At least now I know to #include the corresponding header in the source file as good practice.